# Adding Multiple Conditional Formulas to a Single Custom List

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, calculated-column-formula

Conditional Formulas? Have a formula that will work for comparing 2 items to see if one is not greater than another, but I need to add multiple validations into a single custom list. How do I do this?

=[Item01]<=[Item02]

=[Item03]<=[Item04]

=[Item05]<=[Item06]

=[Item07]<=[Item08]

These work one at a time, but keep getting errors putting them together. (SharePoint 2013 On-Prem)

Comment: What is the error you are getting? please share

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `AND` function to put them together.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/and-function-9ca21054-a466-477e-98bf-fc79e62afb3c

Syntax

```
AND(logical1,logical2,…)
```

Logical1,Logical2,…    are 1 to 30 conditions you want to test that can be either TRUE or FALSE.

So, you could use the formula like this:

```
AND([Item01]<=[Item02],[Item03]<=[Item04],[Item05]<=[Item06],[Item07]<=[Item08])
```

Comment: So simple and worked perfectly. Was so over thinking this!